# Groovy: What is an efficient way extracting multiple data in a string?

Tags: parsing, groovy

I’m making a program that can send an email using a formatted SMS.
Here is the format:

```
to: <example1@example.com, example2@example.com>, cc: <example3@example.com>, 
bcc: <example4@example.com>, subject: "Example",  body: "This is an example."
```

I plan on making cc and bcc optional. So there can be SMS like this:

```
to: <example1@example.com, example2@example.com> subject: "Example", body: "This is an example."
```

I want to store each information in a variable but I’m having a difficult time thinking of a way to parse it in an efficient way.

Here’s how I want to store each information in a variable, using the format as an example.

```
def to = "example1@example.com, example2@example.com"
def cc = "example3@example.com"
def bcc = "example4@example.com"
def subject: "Example"
def body = "This is an example."
```

I’m open to suggestions if anyone has better format in mind.

Comment: wouldnt it be better to have this format? `def to = ["example1@example.com", "example2@example.com"]`

Comment: Also what exactly is your question?

Comment: are you asking for how to make your protocol there better?  that is a bad match for SO.  if you have a programming problem here, please make it more clear, if you have problems parsing etc.  that said `<a@a.org, b@b.org>` will most likely confuse users alot, since `"a name" <email@example.org>` is the way email programs work.

Comment: Can you change the format of the SMS?

Comment: Andy it seems that you are asking us to write the program for you. May I suggest that instead you show us what you have tried and let us work from there?